# How to do certain changes to multiple dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have 4 dataframes, I need to recalculate same column in each dataframe.

I tried to create a list of data frame and then use for loop to iterate the list and apply changes. After the loop if I call the dataframe there is no changes applied to them.

```
List_df=[df1,df2,df3,df4]
For df in List_df:
   Df=df[3:] #triming first 3 rows of data frame
```

So after this code If I call 'df1' to see if changes has been done by for loop or not - sadly it is still just like before the for loop.

Comment: Who's upvoting a question without mcve and displaying zero python knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

You need to invest some time learning how [assignment in Python works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns). Assignment never mutates data. You are just binding a name `Df = ...` to some object and then do nothing with it. Then you rebind the name in the next iteration of the loop.

In addition, `df[3:]` does not trim the first three rows from a DataFrame, `df.iloc[3:]` does.

One solution to your problem is:

```
List_df[:] = [df.iloc[3:] for df in List_df]
```

This operation will mutate `List_df` by inserting *new* DataFrames. You will see the trimmed DataFrames as the elements of `List_df`, but not when you inspect the names `df1`, ..., `df4` after the operation. These names still point to the original DataFrames. (Watch the video.)